# How to access the optgroup value in bootstrapselect onChange event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

i am using a bootstrap-select item in a form and i' d like to get the optgroup value for the selected value when it gets selectet, so i can evaluate what to do based on that groups value:

```
$('select.selectpicker').on('change', function(e){

        var picker_id=e.target.id;
        var selected_value = $('.selectpicker option:selected').val();
        var optgroup = ??

        switch ( optgroup){
            case "group_name":

            break

        }
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: i am getting [Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'selected_value.parent()')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$('select.selectpicker').on('change', function(e){
    var picker_id=e.target.id;
    var selected_option = $(this).find(":selected"); // get selected option for the changed select only
    var selected_value = selected_option.val();
    var optgroup = selected_option.parent().attr('label');

    console.log(optgroup);
    switch ( optgroup){
        case "group_name":

            break

    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tg5s94gp/)

Comment: How get values in object by optgroup?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the optgroups those are in '.selectpicker' class.
If that is the case you can get using

```
$('.selectpicker optgroup').length // will give you optgroups in the   selectpicker.
$('.selectpicker optgroup')[0].label // you can access attributes
```

Comment: thanks. but how do i get the optgroup that belongs to the selected value?